# Can I apply in my original country after my CGI federal profile modification request has been accepted?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, b2visa

I had applied for a B2 visa from my home country and scheduled an appointment. I was unable to get early dates, so I requested a profile modification and transfer to another country. While it was under review, there was a change in my circumstances, and I could not travel. So I requested to cancel the request, but I did not get a response. Instead I got a confirmation of profile modification to the new country in two days time.

Can I still go forward with my appointment in my original country or will it be a problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. But it seems vanishingly unlikely that, having asked for a change in location for your appointment, that the State Dept would change your appointment location and leave the previous location appointment in place.